# Using weak reference to check if object is deallocated, in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using ARC.
Sometimes I wrote the following code to assert a object should be deallocated:

```
__weak weakVariableOrProperty = someObject;
....

someObject = nil;
// or someObject = anotherObject;
....

if (weakVariableOrProperty) {
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:@"Object not deallocated" userInfo:nil];
}
```

For example, I use this code to check if a view controller is deallocated before creating a new view controller.

I believe that weak variable or weak property is set to nil **immediately** after last strong variable or property was set to nil or another object.

And this code is working as I expected until now.

Using weak variable or property to check if object is deallocated is a technique commonly used?
Is it possible that this code will cause problem in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe that weak variable or weak property is set to nil **immediately** after last strong variable or property was set to nil or another object.

This is not exactly true, because an object could be *autoreleased*. In this case, the last strong reference may be gone, but the reference count of the instance would remain positive. In cases like that, the `__weak` reference would not be `nil`-ed out until the autorelease process takes place.

> Is using weak variable or property to check if object is deallocated a technique commonly used?

I seriously doubt that this technique has gained much popularity, because ARC is a relatively new thing to Objective C. However, the technique appears valid.

> Is it possible that this code will cause problem in the future?

This is very hard to guess, because the [ARC Specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) does not make any specific guarantees about the timing of `nil`-ing out the references, and because the spec allows compilers to optimize sequences of `retain` and `release` messages that they send to ARC objects.

Comment: Thank you very much to both dasblinkenlight and @Jesper for good answers.
I will give up the assumption that weak variable is set to nil immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation code will be prone to a race condition.

The object in `weakVariableOrProperty` could be released (since it's only referenced by a weak reference) after the `if` condition has been evaluated. To avoid this, introduce an ordinary variable, set it to `weakVariableOrProperty` and check it for `nil` instead.

That said, as @dasblinkenlight says, betting on exactly *when* an object will be gone is tough. In a reference-counted system you don't know what else is holding onto it. It may go away just after you've checked. You should be able to constrain your environment enough that you know the system's not squirreling things away, but both autorelease and weak references complicate things.

The best way to solve this is simply to have well-defined object lifetimes: view controllers that don't live forever, that you explicitly tell to go away and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried using this technique to ensure that objects are always deallocated on a background thread. The [dealloc] for some of my classes was moderately heavy weight and could take a long time (10s of ms) which would freeze the main thread ever so slightly.

I decided to add all of these heavy objects to an array before they'd be released on the main thread, and then go through that array later on a backgroundd thread to remove them from the array. The thought was that the array would keep the retainCount alive until it could be removed from the array on the background thread, and then i could guarantee the cost of the [dealloc] wouldn't happen on the main thread.

To do this, i had the code below:

```
while([objectsToDealloc count] && /* other conditions to prevent infinite loop */){
    __weak id ref = [objectsToDealloc lastObject];
    [objectsToDealloc removeLastObject];
    @synchronized(ref){
        // synchronising on ref will retain it if possible.
        // so if its still around,that means we didn't dealloc it
        // like we were asked to.
        // so insert it back into our array. once the object is deallocd
        // it won't be able to be synchronized, because the weak ref will
        // be nil
        if(ref){
            [objectsToDealloc insertObject:ref atIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
```

The idea was that if the array didn't contain the last reference (or if there were pending autoreleases on the object, etc), then the weak ref wouldn't nil out. I'd then @synchronize on the object - the synchronized block will retain + release whatever object is being synchronized - which would ensure the `ref` would stay alive during that block. if it was nil, then it'd been dealloced. if it wasn't nil, then i should add it back to the array and check back again later.

After testing with this code over the past few weeks, I cannot recommend this strategy to check for deallocated objects. I haven't tracked down exactly why yet, but very rarely the object will dealloc but the ref won't be nil yet, so i'll be adding an invalid object back into the array.

i've only caught this in the debugger one time, though i have crash logs of it happening a few times. You can see below that "nil" ends up in my array, even though the code above should protect against it.

[image: nil inside an NSArray]

Again, I suggest not using this technique for detecting when/if objects deallocate, and instead focus efforts on clarifying your object graph and relationships.

Comment: Your code does not protect against inserting a `nil` object in the array. Because `ref` is weak, it can be deallocated in between `if(ref)` and `[objectsToDealloc insertObject:ref atIndex:0]`. (For example, if the object is an autoreleased object, and the autorelease pool drains on another thread.)

Comment: That's why i'm using the synchronized block. When inspecting the assembly for the synchronized block, i saw that it adds [retain] at its start and then [release] the object at the end. so inside the synchronized, if the ref is not nil, it will stay not nil b/c it's been retained.



also, the nil shown at index 1 couldn't have been added by the [insertObject:] call, b/c it throws an exception when trying to insert nil.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think the retain/release behavior of `@synchronized` is documented (so there may be exceptions to this behavior). Your second point is definitely valid, and I cannot think of an explanation for it.

Comment: The [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) lists `NSAutoreleasePool` as a thread-unsafe class. Perhaps a timing issue, but I can't think of an order that would cause the issue you're seeing.